# How can I have a nested loop with a fileglob pattern?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a set of authorized SSH keys for a set of users in Ansible. I have a `users` variable set up like so:

```
users:
  - { username: root, name: 'root' }
  - { username: user, name: 'User' }
```

In the same role, I also have a set of authorized key files in a `files/public_keys` directory, one file per authorized key:

```
roles/common/files/public_keys/home
roles/common/files/public_keys/work
```

I want to copy each public key to each user.

I have tried using the following task:

```
- name: copy authorized keys
  authorized_key: user={{ item.0.username }} key={{ item.1 }}
  with_nested:
    - users
    - lookup('fileglob', 'public_keys/*')
```

However, `item.1` contains the literal string `"lookup('fileglob', 'public_keys/*')"`, not each file path under `files/public_keys`.

Is there a way I can get a listing of the `files/public_keys` directory and copy each public key to each user?

Answer (score 12):

The trick is to transform the fileglob return value into a list via the `split` function, so you can iterate over the values:

```
- name: copy authorized keys
  authorized_key: 
    user: "{{ item.0.username }}"
    key: "{{ lookup('file', item.1) }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ users }}"
    - "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'public_keys/*').split(',') }}"
```

Note that using bare variables, without `{{` and `}}`, for `with_items` was deprecated in Ansible v2.

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You might have to significantly rewrite your command, but there's provision for [looping over fileglobs](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-fileglobs)

from the example:

```
- copy: src={{ item }} dest=/etc/fooapp/ owner=root mode=600
  with_fileglob:
    - /playbooks/files/fooapp/*
```

Other promising options are [Looping over Subelements](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements) which is actually illustrated by SSH keys

Comment: I know you can loop over file globs using `with_fileglob`; I'm just not sure how to use that in conjunction with a nested loop. Looping over subelements _could_ work, but I'm hoping I don't have to manually specify the entire list of keys I want to copy, since I _should_ just be able to get that as a list (using `with_fileglob`).

Comment: I'm not sure either.  The next best suggestion is to pop into `#ansible` on `irc.freenode.net` and see if the gurus there have any bright ideas.

Answer (score 0):

for me this was working only in this form

```
    - name: Set up authorized keys for root
      authorized_key:
        user: root
        state: present
        key: "{{ lookup('file', item) }}"
      with_fileglob: 'public_keys/*.pub'
```