# Ansible: How to iterate over the results of fileglobs which are called for every element of a list?

Tags: ansible

I want to do something very similar as mentioned in [How can I have a nested loop with a fileglob pattern?](https://serverfault.com/questions/649721/how-can-i-have-a-nested-loop-with-a-fileglob-pattern) except that the list of files is a glob pattern which refers to the items from the outer loop.

My (failing) code so far:

```
    - name: Deploy authorized_keys files for users
      authorized_key:
        user: "{{ item }}"
        key: "{{ query('fileglob', 'ssh-pub-keys/{{ item }}/*.pub') }}"
      with_list:
        - user1
        - user2
```

The directory `ssh-pub-keys` looks as follows:

```
ssh-pub-keys
├── user1
│   ├── hostA_id_ecdsa.pub
│   ├── hostA_id_ed25519.pub
│   ├── hostB_id_ecdsa.pub
│   ├── hostB_id_ed25519.pub
│   └── hostB_id_rsa.pub
└── user2
    ├── hostC_id_ecdsa.pub
    ├── hostC_id_rsa.pub
    ├── hostD_id_ecdsa.pub
    └── hostD_id_ed25519.pub
```

The error message looks like this:

```
failed: [somehost] (item=user1) => {"changed": false, "item": "user1", "msg": "invalid key specified: ['…/ssh-pub-keys/user1/hostA_id_ecdsa.pub', '…/ssh-pub-keys/user1/hostA_id_ed25519.pub', …]"}
failed: [somehost] (item=user2) => {"changed": false, "item": "user2", "msg": "invalid key specified: ['…/ssh-pub-keys/user2/hostC_id_ecdsa.pub', '…/ssh-pub-keys/user2/hostC_id_rsa.pub', …]"}
```

I don't seem to be able to use `with_nested` as I can't refer from the one list to other one.

Also tried Ansible/Jinja2 filters like `loop: {{ ['user1','user2'] | product(query(('fileglob', 'ssh-pub-keys/{{ ??? }}/*.pub'')) | list }}`, but didn't figure out how to refer to the items from the first list inside `product(…)`…

Another try was to use two tasks with the second referring to the first's registered output, but I didn't figure out how to make shell output into a proper data structure (output split by space, but keeping the information which input item was used) again:

```
    - name: Enumerate all authorized_keys files for all users
      shell: "echo ssh-pub-keys/{{ item }}/*.pub"
      with_list:
        - user1
        - user2
      register: keyfiles
```

Anyone knows how these kind of tasks are implemented properly?

P.S.: Using Ansible 2.7.7 as available in Debian 10 Buster (current Debian stable release).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to concatenate the keys. Quoting from [authorized_key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html#authorized-key-adds-or-removes-an-ssh-authorized-key):

> *Multiple keys can be specified in a single key string value by separating them by newlines.*

For example

```
- name: Deploy authorized_keys files for users
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item }}"
    key: |
      {% for fn in lookup('fileglob', 'ssh-pub-keys/' ~ item ~ '/*.pub', wantlist=True) %}
      {{ lookup('file', fn) }}
      {% endfor %}
  loop:
    - user1
    - user2
```